# Stability of a system of two second order, linear difference equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, stability-theory

I have a system of two linear difference equations in the form:

$$
x_{1,t+2}=-Ax_{1t}-Bx_{1,t+1}-Cx_{2t}-Dx_{2,t+1}+Ex_{2,t+2}+F
$$
$$
x_{2,t+2}=Gx_{2t}-Hx_{2,t+1}+Ix_{1t}+Jx_{1,t+1}-Kx_{1,t+2}+L
$$

where A-L are some constants. What would be a way to solve the general solution & analyze the stability of the equilibrium state?

Thank you!

EDIT: Added specific functions.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please add more details on the functions $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Added specific function forms, thank you for the comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be rewritten as

$$X(t+1)=MX(t)+N$$

for some suitable vector $X(t)$ and matrices $M$ and $N$.

The fixed points $X^*$ can be found by solving $X^*=MX^*+N$.

The stability of the equilibrium points can be studied by looking at the eigenvalues of the matrix $M$ which must be in the unit disc. Some eigenvalues can be located on the unit circle under certain conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! To clarify: Rewriting the problem as X(t+1)=MX(t)+N means that I should create new variables using the idea k1(t)=x1(t),k2(t)=x1(t+1),k1(t+1)=k2(t), k2(t+1)=x1(t+2), in order to create the system of first order difference equations?

Comment: Yes, you can place $x_{1,t}$, $x_{1,t+1}$, $x_{2,t}$, and $x_{2,t+1}$ in the vector $X(t)$ the way you want. For instance, you can pick $X(t)=(x_{1,t},x_{2,t},x_{1,t+1},x_{2,t+1})$ and build the matrices $M$ and $N$, accordingly.